# Select in Hibernate has same duration with or without statistics

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I currently have an abnormally slow simple SELECT. I find it slow because it just does :
SELECT * from myTable where idNonIndex1 = 1 and idNonIndex2 = 2

The cause of the slowness could have been the non-indexed ids, but when I compare the execution of this query in Java6/Hibernate3 with Java11/Hibernate5, it takes 10 times longer with Hibernate5. Yet I've tried to configure them in a similar way, I need to migrate to Hibernate5 for my project.
I've tried several things for the query: Criteria, CriteriaQuery, HQL. Currently, the Java6/Hibernate3 - Java11/Hibernate5 comparison is done with Criteria.

And I've observed something even stranger:
when I enable Hibernate5 statistics, requests take as long as when statistics are disabled. And yet, statistics are supposed to greatly increase request times. I've debugged Hibernate5 to check that statistics are indeed disabled under normal circumstances, but I feel like I'm missing something.
Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Why not just take query plans and compare those

Comment: @siggemannen it's the exact same request on both versions

Comment: At least three bits in `@@OPTIONS` are plan-affecting options, so they affect the performance of queries. That is to say that even though the submitted queries might be byte-for-byte identical they can still perform quite differently when different `@@OPTIONS` are in effect. Do the Hibernate 3/5 requests produce different plans (`plan_handle`s)? Are the [`set_options`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql#c-returning-the-set-options-with-which-the-plan-was-compiled) different?